# Sorting on two columns in pandas in an unusual way

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this :

```
col_1 | serial_number | remaining time

B     |            17 | 02:45
A     |            02 | 02:00
C     |            25 | 03:30
A     |            03 | 03:00
B     |            12 | 03:45
C     |            07 | 01:30
C     |            89 | 02:30
B     |            45 | 01:45
A     |            01 | 01:00
```

And I'd like to sort on remaining time (lowest at the top) BUT col_1 should be grouped. Here's what the above dataframe would would look like.

```
col_1 | serial_number | remaining time

A     |            01 | 01:00
A     |            02 | 02:00
A     |            03 | 03:00
C     |            07 | 01:30
C     |            89 | 02:30
C     |            25 | 03:30
B     |            45 | 01:45
B     |            17 | 02:45
B     |            12 | 03:45
```

I'm not able to do it at the moment. First I need to sort by remaining time, then group col_1 together.

Comment: Isn't `sort_values(['col_1', 'remaining_time'])` what you need then?

Comment: can you please explain where is `groupby` applied to your  data ?

Comment: @jdehesa It would then sort on 'col_1' first. Making it 'A', 'B', 'C' in that order. I need to first check the remaining time, then group 'col_1' together

Comment: @grubjesic I think it was indeed a mistake, i'm editing it out

Comment: @jdoe why is 17 before 45 in your final dataframe? They both have `B`, but are unsorted in remaining time.

Comment: @AmiTavory I edit that out. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`groupby` + `transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html)

```
df['remaining_time_group_min'] = df['remaining time'].groupby(df.col_1).transform(min)
```

to create a new column which has, for each element, the minimum time for any member of its group.

Following that, as   jdehesa suggested in the comments, you can use

```
df.sort_values(['remaining_time_group_min', 'remaining time'])
```

Comment: This solution seems the easiest for me !
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Create [ordered catagorical](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) of column `col_1` and sort:

```
cats = df.sort_values(['remaining time'])['col_1'].unique()
print (cats)
['A' 'C' 'B']

df['col_1'] = pd.Categorical(df['col_1'], categories=cats, ordered=True)
df = df.sort_values([ 'col_1', 'remaining time'])
print (df)
  col_1 serial_number remaining time
8     A            01          01:00
1     A            02          02:00
3     A            03          03:00
5     C            07          01:30
6     C            89          02:30
2     C            25          03:30
7     B            45          01:45
0     B            17          02:45
4     B            12          03:45
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['col_1'])
8    A
1    A
3    A
5    C
6    C
2    C
7    B
0    B
4    B
Name: col_1, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [A < C < B]
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating your `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':['B','A','C','A','B','C','C','B','A'], 'serial_number':[17,2,25,3,12,7,89,45,1],'remaining time':['02:45','02:00','03:30','03:00','03:45','01:30','02:30','01:45','01:00']})
df['remaining time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['remaining time'])
df['remaining time'] = [time.time() for time in df['remaining time']]
```

Add a new column with the minimum time per group:

```
df['min time'] =  df.groupby('col_1')['remaining time'].transform(min)
```

Then sort by this new minimum time followed by the actual time remaining:

```
>>> df.sort_values(by=['min time','remaining time'])
  col_1 remaining time  serial_number  min time
8     A       01:00:00              1  01:00:00
1     A       02:00:00              2  01:00:00
3     A       03:00:00              3  01:00:00
5     C       01:30:00              7  01:30:00
6     C       02:30:00             89  01:30:00
2     C       03:30:00             25  01:30:00
7     B       01:45:00             45  01:45:00
0     B       02:45:00             17  01:45:00
4     B       03:45:00             12  01:45:00
```